# Authenticating to blockchain from a Java client?

Tags: rest, swagger, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I have a blockchain network built using Hyperledger Composer, started the Composer Rest Server and generated Java client code from the Open API spec to consume the REST Api. I have looked at the documentation to enable authentication and multi user mode. I already have authentication in my web application. How would I go about granting access to the user to interact with the blockchain after they sign into my web app? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please tell us what strategy are you using for your web-application authentication?

Recently updated documentation @ https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/enabling-rest-authentication

```
The REST server uses the open source Passport authentication middleware. 
Administrators of the REST server must select Passport strategies to 
authenticate clients. Multiple Passport strategies can be selected, allowing 
clients of the REST server to select a preferred authentication mechanism. 
Passport includes a wide range of strategies (300+ at the time of writing), 
including a mix of social media (Google, Facebook, Twitter) and enterprise 
(SAML, LDAP) strategies.
```

You need to configure an appropriate `passport-strategy` to generate the `access_token` that will be used by REST API SERVER.

Comment: I am using Apache Shiro to handle authentication in my Java web app. The web app is just running locally and uses an email and password to login. I'm guessing the local passport stratedgy would work best?  When they are authenticated to the app, I want that to trigger the authentication process for the blockchain.

Comment: `When they are authenticated to the app, I want that to trigger the authentication process for the blockchain.` You will be running the `composer-rest-server` in multi-user mode. After you implement your `passport` strategy. You need to add a hook into your existing login method to POST the username/pass word to `/auth/your-strategy-name` and get the `access_token` in response, in order for `rest-composer-server` to work, you need to send that `access_token` with every request.

Comment: This composer-rest test case for ldap-server (https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/blob/1ab127897ff30c419913d06942191dad4f0c2312/packages/composer-rest-server/test/ldapserver.js#L26) really helped me understand how it works. I hope it does the same for you.